# Datatables Editor : New record to be created with an user ID provided from backend

Tags: php, datatables

I have a MySQL table in backend that stores user's information and the primary Key is an AUTO iNCREMENT number which I use to identify the user.

I am using Datatables editor to edit / delete / new records on this table. However since ID of each user's is unique I have disabled them for editing at Web page by below function:

```
editor.on( 'onInitCreate', function () {
    editor.disable('id');
} );
editor.on( 'onInitEdit', function () {
    editor.disable('id');
} );
```

This way the user viewing the web page cannot edit / modify the uid value. But the issue is that when creating a new User record I have to show the id value next available from the backend at create new web page.

Say the last user id number is 65, so when user clicks on New button it should show an non-editable value of User id as 66 with other editable blank form values and so on each time the new record is getting created.

At present I am just using the below format:

```
include( "DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Join,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;
Editor::inst( $db, 'datatables_demo' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'id' ),
        .............

    )
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

**EDIT::**

On another hand I realized that the value can be unreliable at front end because another web user / admin could also try inserting a row simultaneously. That would mean that when the user clicks on Submit on Create New record form, the new user table should be updated and before the new record form is dismissed the UID value should be displayed.